# Kill app whenever it goes to background

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am creating an app. From `MainActivity -> Fragment -> See Details Activity`.

It is working fine.

But when I am going to background on See `Details Activity`, it is still running.

Why this activity or app is not getting destroyed. I want to kill the app whenever I will go to background.

Comment: Do you mean you want to kill previous activity?

Comment: did you read the article about activity lifecycle? http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html (or any similar?) if you have, can you please be more specific about your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
@Override public void onPause() { super.onPause(); // Always call the superclass method first
Finish();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Invoke `finish()` method before start Fragment

Comment: Really? You will finish the activity on which fragment is loaded?